# Jenkins Pipeline: Send perforce changes per Email

Tags: jenkins, version-control, perforce, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to know how I can send Sourcecode-Changes between two jenkins-pipeline builds can be sned per Email durring the build. The last step of the build already send an email with informations for developers for deployed artifacts. I would like to send the perforce changelist-description (maybe also user wh made the change(s) and date/time of the change(s)) within this email. We using Jenkins ver. 2.52 and pipeline-script from SCM as build-type.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `p4 changes -l @chg1,@chg2`, in broad strokes, will get you the information you need to include in your mail.

Comment: What do you mean with @chg1, @chg2? Ist this a jenkins-environment-variable or what is it?

Comment: Those would be the two Perforce changelist numbers that are associated with the "two jenkins-pipeline builds" that you mentioned in your question. Specifying a pair of Perforce changelist numbers as a "range" is how you ask Perforce about the changes between two points in time. Try `p4 help revisions` to learn more about this.